# opening files from blender 4.0 to 2.79b

Tags: blend-files

I mainly use the newest blender version (4.0) but my school uses 2.79b and can't update from that. What can I do to open files from the newest version to 2.79b

Comment: Have you tried File > Append?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Blend files are supposed to always be forward-compatible but only backwards-compatible up to a certain point.

Comment: As Gorgious mentions things are backwards compatible to a certain point, but 2.79 is really pushing it, even from 2.8. Also Blender can run portably from a thumb drive. Unless the system is fully lock down you can use whatever version from portable storage as you please

Comment: And what I would do in your case, if you are working with 2.79b in your school and you are making files for your school, just install 2.79b alongside your 4.0 so that you can do school stuff on the old version. You can get all versions from the Blender website (not right now because blender.org seems to be down, but as soon as it is up again). //EDIT: Just read there was a DDoS attack on blender.org

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, since version 4.0 is a major version update, it can and did break compatibility with older versions. I think your best bet is to export your assets individually or the whole scene to another format like OBJ. Then, you can import them in version 2.79b. You may need to do some cleanup afterwards.